# Проблемы с импортом в Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

У меня есть два приложения, которые я хочу залить на pythonanywhere.com . Так исторически сложилось, что одно вообще не использует сторонних модулей(ну flask не в счет), а второе - тянем достаточно приличное их кол-во(vk, vk_api, threat). С первым проблем не возникло. Но вот второе начинает возмущаться, что нету моделей. Я пробовал их ставить через pip в bash, не помогало, импорт в wgisi файл тоже не работал(может я это сделал неправильно). Как можно решить мою проблему?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь виртуальным окружением, заранее прописав `requirements.txt`.

Comment: _"пробовал их ставить через pip в bash"_, — не ошиблись интерпретатором? А вообще лучше системный не трогать.

Comment: Я честно говоря, не особо в курсе, как работает виртуальное окружение, не подскажете, где можно про это поподробнее прочитать? Или где есть инструкция по осуществлению чего-то подобного. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Я ошибся версией интерпритатора, писал pip3 install ... Но забыл тот факт, что пользуюсь не самой новой веткой патйона. Надо было писать pip3.7 install.... После того. как я доставил все нужные модули, все заработало. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было использовать правильную версию pip-а, а именно pip3.7

Comment: Лучше использовать виртуальные окружения, чтобы не путаться в интерпретаторах. Почитать можно здесь например: https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-17-virtual-envs/

Comment: Согласен с вами, обязательно прочитаю статью.